# Getting error "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE" from Okta JWT Verifier

Tags: node.js, okta, okta-api

Trying to verify Okta token using @okta/jwt-verifier module but getting below error

```
 parsedBody: JwtBody {
    ver: 1,
    jti: 'xxxxxxx',
    iss: 'xxxxxxx',
    aud: 'api://default',
    iat: 1596797376,
    exp: 1596800976,
    cid: 'xxxxxxxx',
    uid: 'xxxxxxxx',
    scp: [ 'profile', 'openid', 'email' ],
    sub: 'XXX@gmail.com'
  },
  innerError: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1501:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12) {
    code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' 
  }
```